# How can we do conditional through in has_many association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

[DB Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJB5c.png)

So basically I've four tables and respective models for them in rails.

```
class A < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to D
  has_many B
  has_many C through: {
                        if is_safe -> D 
                        else -> B
                      }
end

class B < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to A
  belongs_to C
end

class C < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to D
  has_many B
end

class D < ApplicationRecord
  has_many A
  has_many C
end
```

How can I write the `has_many C :through` statement mentioned in model A such that it depends on the value of `is_safe`.

Comment: This idea won't work since associations are evaluated at class level - not instance level. You can't actually choose which assocation an association goes through based on the instance as that would make stuff like `A.joins(:b).where(bs: { c: 1 })` impossible due to circular logic.

Answer (score 0):

you could have 2 `has_many(s)` one through D and one through B then have a method that decides which association to return

```rb
class A < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to D
  has_many B
  
  has_many C_D, through: D, class_name: "C"
  has_many C_B, through: B, class_name: "C"


  def Cs
    if is_safe
        C_D
    else
        C_B
    end
  end
end
```